# Создание списка окон, получение их handle и title на C#

Tags: c#

С# Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачи: необходимо получить полный список задач (окон, т.е. тех которые видимы в режиме alt+Tab), запущенных на компе и доступ к ним (хотя бы минимальный: координаты, размер окна).
А то предыдущий способ через Process.GetProcesses() не увенчался успехом ибо один процесс может иметь несколько окон с разными hwnd...

[image: должно получиться вот такого плана]

Comment: О каких "задачах" речь? И, главное, что это за координаты задачи? Один процесс это один процесс, он может порождать много потоков, но при чем тут координаты? Дополняйте вопрос. И да C# - не лучший язык реализации для такого.

Comment: В Windows есть понятие Child Process (это процесс, порожденный другим процессом). Про координаты я сам не понял.

Comment: @Raider только процесс-потомок будет все так же процессом, а не "задачей".

Comment: Автор видимо по аналогии с Диспетчером задач перевел Process как задачу.

Comment: На скриншоте разве не видно какие задачи ? "Task" Задачи в основном имеют окна, а значит имеют и координаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем, если у кого-то будет стоять подобная задача, то вот как я смог ее решить:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",
    ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd,
        StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows",
    ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop,
        EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);

    // Define the callback delegate's type.
    private delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

    // Save window titles and handles in these lists.
    private static List<IntPtr> WindowHandles;
    private static List<string> WindowTitles;

    // Return a list of the desktop windows' handles and titles.
    public static void GetDesktopWindowHandlesAndTitles(
        out List<IntPtr> handles, out List<string> titles)
    {
        WindowHandles = new List<IntPtr>();
        WindowTitles = new List<string>();

        if (!EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, FilterCallback, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            handles = null;
            titles = null;
        }
        else
        {
            handles = WindowHandles;
            titles = WindowTitles;
        }
    }

    // We use this function to filter windows.
    // This version selects visible windows that have titles.
    private static bool FilterCallback(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
    {
        // Get the window's title.
        StringBuilder sb_title = new StringBuilder(1024);
        int length = GetWindowText(hWnd, sb_title, sb_title.Capacity);
        string title = sb_title.ToString();

        // If the window is visible and has a title, save it.
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) == false)
        {
            WindowHandles.Add(hWnd);
            WindowTitles.Add(title);
        }

        // Return true to indicate that we
        // should continue enumerating windows.
        return true;
    }
```